# Differentiable complex line bundles are determined by their Chern class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}$)?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, line-bundles

The statement: differentiable complex line bundles are determined by their Chern class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}$) is from Wells' book p.105, which I attached below (also the statement of theorem 4.5 is attached).

[image]

[image]

I feel very confused about this statement. My understanding is fist we use that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the equivalence classes of differentiable line bundles on $X$ and the elements of the cohomology group $H_1(X,\epsilon^*)$, where $\epsilon^*$ means non-vanishing differentiable structure sheaf. And by the isomorphism of $H^1(X,\epsilon^*)\cong H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, we can determine the equivalent classes of equivalence classes of differentiable line bundles via the elements of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. However, the Chern classes are in $H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ or more precisely, $\tilde{H}^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, where $\tilde{H}^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the image of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ from the homomorphism from $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ induced by the inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ of constant sheaf. But we don't have that Chern classes are in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. I don't understand how to determine the line bundles via the classes are in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: There are various ways to define Chern classes. One of them will get you classes in $H^2(X, \mathbb{R})$, but this definition loses information; other definitions define a class in $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ and this is the one you want.

Comment: I think Wells is clear enough. A line bundle has a *Chern class* which is an element of $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$. This agrees with the definition in Wikipedia. It also has a *real Chern class* which is the image of the Chern class under the natural map from $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ to $H^2(X,\Bbb R)$. The Chern class determines the isomorphism class of the line bundle, the real Chern class may not.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If you check Wells' book, he didn't mention what you said, although your words make sense to me, thx anyway

Comment: @QiaochuYuan then by $H^1(X,\epsilon^*)\cong H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, does it mean very element in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ determines a differentiable line bundle over $X$?

Comment: Yes, that's also true.